# In as3 adjusting brightness of the shape is not working via coding

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

This is my following code.

```
var clips:Array=new Array(clip_0_mc,clip_1_mc,clip_2_mc,clip_3_mc,clip_4_mc);
trace(clips);

clips[0].alpha=.5;
clips[3].rotation=45;
clips[3].brightness=100;// This is not working.
clips[1].rotation=170;
```

I tried alpha and rotation tat is perfect. but brightness is not working.

Answer (score 6):

Well there is no brightness property for MovieClips so that is not surprising.

You can use [ColorTransform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html) with [fl.motion.Color](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/motion/Color.html) to change brightness.

```
import flash.geom.Transform;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import fl.motion.Color;
//...
var color:Color = new Color();
color.brightness = 0.3;         
clips[3].transform.colorTransform = color;
```

Comment: @PraveenBabu: You're welcome. Make sure to accept the answer so that others know that the question is resolved. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work