# Includeing fl.motion.Color

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I was reading this post: [In as3 adjusting brightness of the shape is not working via coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786594/in-as3-adjusting-brightness-of-the-shape-is-not-working-via-coding), and it says to import "fl.motion.Color," but it doesn't seem to be in the default library. How do I include it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include the fl library.

You can find it in your installation folder under:

*\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5\en\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\Classes*

You would need to have Adobe Flash CS5 (or other version) installed.